# MYSQL Calculated Values

Tags: mysql

I have 3 Tables

**1. salary_earning**

```
CREATE TABLE `salary_earning` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `basic_salary` int NOT NULL,
  `health_allowance` int NOT NULL,
  `transport_allowance` int NOT NULL,
  `overtime_allowance` int NOT NULL,
  `leave_encashment` int NOT NULL,
  `accomodation_allowance` int NOT NULL,
  `bonus_allowance` int NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

```
INSERT INTO `salary_earning` (`id`, `basic_salary`, `health_allowance`, `transport_allowance`, `overtime_allowance`, `leave_encashment`, `accomodation_allowance`, `bonus_allowance`, `emp_id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 'DO-123', '2020-10-02'),
(2, 1000, 200, 100, 50, 300, 500, 200, 'DO-456', '2020-10-02');
```

**2. salary_deduction**

```
CREATE TABLE `salary_deduction` (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `income_tax` int NOT NULL,
 `advance_money` int NOT NULL,
 `emp_id` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

```
INSERT INTO `salary_deduction` (`id`, `income_tax`, `advance_money`, `emp_id`, `date`) VALUES
(2, 1000, 1000, 'DO-123', '2020-10-02'),
(3, 200, 300, 'DO-456', '2020-10-02');
```

**3. salary_final**

```
CREATE TABLE `salary_final` (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `emp_id` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `total_earning` int NOT NULL,
 `total_deduction` int NOT NULL,
 `final_salary` int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Data is being inserted into earning(tbl1) and deduction(tbl2). I want salary_final table to calculated "final_salary = total_earning - total_deduction" based on the distinctive emp_id from other 2 tables and populate 3rd table.

I am new to SQL, am I doing it the right way by creating a new table? or just creating mysqview is enough for this kind of requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some test data for two first tables. I mean you should to create `VIEW` instead third table

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Is this fiddle match your desired result: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=ff3b6b5ba6cbe5ae78fcb9245d3bf984&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80

Comment: Its working thank you so much